# ACF link withing website is good, but not external link?

Tags: jquery, advanced-custom-fields, links

I'm using this ACF loop (repeater field) where one field for linkedin is beign display:

```
<?php foreach($people_one['directors'] as $directors): ?>

<div class="col-five">

<div class="hover-wrapper">
<img class="colour" src="<?php echo $directors['main_image']['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $directors['main_image']['alt']; ?>" />
<img class="grey" src="<?php echo $directors['grey_image']['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $directors['grey_image']['alt']; ?>" />
<div class="hover-content">
<div class="align-wrapper">

<p><?php echo $directors['e-mail'] ?></p>

<p><?php echo $directors['phone'] ?></p>

<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $directors['linkedin'] ?>"><img class="linkedin-directors" width="40px" src="img"></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
  <h3><?php echo $directors['name'] ?></h3>
     <p><?php echo $directors['position'] ?></p>


</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

the problem is on click in the fron end on the link it bring to:

http:mysite.com/mylink.com

instead of http://mylink.com

If anyone have any idea / help. ..  it will be superb !!

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0):

That will happen if the link doesn't include http:// in it. For example, if the user has entered just `linkedin.com` into the field. In that case `<a href="linkedin.com">` will be treated as a relative link by the browser.

Use `esc_url` on output to ensure a full valid URL with protocol is output:

```
<?php echo esc_url( $directors['linkedin'] ); ?>
```

PS: The URL field in ACF, rather than just a text field, has validation that would help with this.